else срабатывает вместе с if (python)
A = int (input ("Введите номер месяца: "))
if A == 1:
    print ("Январь. Зима, холода, одинокие дома...")
if A == 2:
    print ("Февраль. Зима, холода, всё как будто изо льда")
if A == 3:
    print ("Март. Весна... Снова коты орать будут =(")
if A == 4:
    print ("Апрель. Весна.")
if A == 5:
    print ("Май. Весна.")
if A == 6:
    print ("Июнь. Лето")
if A == 7:
    print ("Июль. Жаркое солнце больших городов... (Лето)")
if A == 8:
    print ("Август. Лето.")
if A == 9:
    print ("Сентябрь. Осень.")
if A == 10:
    print ("Октябрь. Да здравствует сезон сбора урожая! (Осень)")
if A == 11:
    print ("Ноябрь. Все засыпает... (Осень)")
if A == 12:
    print ("Декабрь. С наступающим! (Зима)")
else:
    print ("Ещё не придумали больше 12 месяцев -_-")

Вот сам код. При вводе чисел от 1 до 11 выводит else вместе с if. При вводе числа 12 выводит только if.

Все правильно, т.к. у вас разные IF. Вам нужно либо elif использовать, либо switch-case(match). Вот почитайте

Благодарствую. Просто я его только начал изучать, потому такие глупые вопросы задаю.

При изучении хуже, когда вопросов нет.

Проблема заключается в том, что для месяцев 1-11 в последнем if
if A == 12:
    print ("Декабрь. С наступающим! (Зима)")
else:
    print ("Ещё не придумали больше 12 месяцев -_-")

условие A == 12 не будет выполнено и потому заработает ветвь else.
(Как это исправить, вам уже подсказали в комментарии.)
